# PolylineOptions cannot be null and no route appear

Tags: java, android-studio, google-maps, kotlin, routes

I need your help, i'm trying to do an application in Kotlin on Android Studio but I have a problem.

On a part of this application I try to show the route between two point but i have a mistake. At the beginning the mistake was that i get the "java.lang.NullPointerException: PolylineOptions cannot be null." , i solve it by adding a " if(polylineOptions != null){ " , but now the problem is that i don't get any error but the route between the two point don't appear.

Here is the code of my class concern by this problem :

```
class ViewDirections : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap

lateinit var mService: IGoogleAPIService

companion object { private const val MY_PERMISSION_CODE: Int = 1000 }

lateinit var mCurrentMarker: Marker

var polyLine:Polyline?=null

lateinit var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
lateinit var locationRequest: LocationRequest
lateinit var locationCallback: LocationCallback
lateinit var mLastLocation:Location

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_direction)
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)

    mService = Common.googleApiServiceScalars

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    {
        if(checkLocationPermission())
        {
            buildLocationRequest()
            buildLocationCallBack()

            fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
            fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.myLooper())

        }
    }
    else
    {
        buildLocationRequest()
        buildLocationCallBack()

        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.myLooper())
    }

}

private fun checkLocationPermission(): Boolean {
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                ViewDirections.MY_PERMISSION_CODE
            )
        else
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                ViewDirections.MY_PERMISSION_CODE
            )
        return false
    }
    else
    {
        return true
    }
}

//override onRequestPermissionResult
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    when(requestCode)
    {
        ViewDirections.MY_PERMISSION_CODE ->{
            if(grantResults.size > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    if(checkLocationPermission())
                    {
                        buildLocationRequest()
                        buildLocationCallBack()

                        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
                        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.myLooper())

                        mMap.isMyLocationEnabled=true
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun buildLocationRequest() {
    locationRequest = LocationRequest()
    locationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
    locationRequest.interval = 5000
    locationRequest.fastestInterval = 3000
    locationRequest.smallestDisplacement = 10f

    //Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "latitude: $latitude \n longitude : $longitude", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}

private fun buildLocationCallBack() {
    locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
        override fun onLocationResult(p0: LocationResult?) {
            mLastLocation = p0!!.lastLocation

            val markerOptions = MarkerOptions()
                .position(LatLng(mLastLocation.latitude, mLastLocation.longitude))
                .title("Votre position")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE))

            mCurrentMarker = mMap!!.addMarker(markerOptions)

            mMap!!.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(LatLng(mLastLocation.latitude, mLastLocation.longitude)))
            mMap!!.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12.0f))

            //Position destination
            val destinationLatLng = LatLng(Common.currentResult!!.geometry!!.location!!.lat.toDouble(),
                Common.currentResult!!.geometry!!.location!!.lng.toDouble())

            mMap!!.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(destinationLatLng)
                .title(Common.currentResult!!.name)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)))

            //Itineraire
            drawPath(mLastLocation, Common.currentResult!!.geometry!!.location!!)

        }
    }
}

private fun drawPath(mLastLocation: Location?, location: com.example.finder.Model.Location) {
    if(polyLine != null)
        polyLine!!.remove()

    val origin = StringBuilder(mLastLocation!!.latitude.toString())
        .append(",")
        .append(mLastLocation!!.longitude.toString())
        .toString()

    val destination = StringBuilder(location.lat.toString())
        .append(",")
        .append(location.lng.toString())
        .toString()

    mService.getDirections(origin, destination )
        .enqueue(object:Callback<String>{
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<String>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d("FINDER", t.message)
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<String>, response: Response<String>) {
                ParserTask().execute(response!!.body()!!.toString())
            }
        })
}

override fun onStop() {
    fusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback)
    super.onStop()
}

override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap

    mMap.uiSettings.isZoomControlsEnabled = true

    fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener { location ->
        mLastLocation = location

        val markerOptions = MarkerOptions()
            .position(LatLng(mLastLocation.latitude, mLastLocation.longitude))
            .title("Votre position")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE))

        mCurrentMarker = mMap!!.addMarker(markerOptions)

        mMap!!.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(LatLng(mLastLocation.latitude, mLastLocation.longitude)))
        mMap!!.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12.0f))

        //Position destination
        val destinationLatLng = LatLng(Common.currentResult!!.geometry!!.location!!.lat.toDouble(),
            Common.currentResult!!.geometry!!.location!!.lng.toDouble())

        mMap!!.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(destinationLatLng)
            .title(Common.currentResult!!.name)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)))

        //Itineraire
        drawPath(mLastLocation, Common.currentResult!!.geometry!!.location!!)
    }
}

inner class ParserTask:AsyncTask<String,Int,List<List<HashMap<String,String>>>>(){
    internal val waitingDialog = SpotsDialog(this@ViewDirections)

    override fun onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute()
        waitingDialog.show()
        waitingDialog.setMessage("Veuillez patienter...")
    }

    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String?): List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>? {
        val jsonObject:JSONObject
        var routes: List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>?=null
        try{
            jsonObject = JSONObject(params[0])
            val parser = DirectionJSONParser()
            routes = parser.parse(jsonObject)
        }catch (e:JSONException){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return routes
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>?) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)

        var points:ArrayList<LatLng>?=null
        var polylineOptions:PolylineOptions?=null

        for(i in result!!.indices){
            points = ArrayList()
            polylineOptions = PolylineOptions()

            val path = result[i]

            for(j in path.indices){
                val point = path[j]
                val lat = point["lat"]!!.toDouble()
                val lng = point["lng"]!!.toDouble()
                val position = LatLng(lat, lng)

                points.add(position)
            }

            polylineOptions.addAll(points)
            polylineOptions.width(12f)
            polylineOptions.color(Color.RED)
            polylineOptions.geodesic(true)

        }

        if(polylineOptions != null){
            mMap!!.addPolyline(polylineOptions)
        }

        waitingDialog.dismiss()

    }

}
```

}

And here are the log when i launch the app until I try to get the route :

```
05/26 13:03:56: Launching 'app' on SELECLINE S3T10IN.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.finder/com.example.finder.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 13379 on device 'selecline-s3t10in-86649d48090700000000'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
I/MultiDex: Installing application
I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 32.548ms
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1591(87KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 3% free, 3MB/3MB, paused 43.151ms total 74.669ms
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 118(29KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 40% free, 3MB/5MB, paused 5.382ms total 69.205ms
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: false
D/Atlas: Validating map...
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
I/zzbz: Making Creator dynamically
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:201816000
    Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite, version >= 201816000
W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 9532(692KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(13KB) LOS objects, 14% free, 4MB/5MB, paused 3.301ms total 111.495ms
I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 11910000
I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 201816006
W/ContextImpl: Failed to ensure directory: /storage/extsd/Android/data/com.example.finder/cache
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 17115(1414KB) AllocSpace objects, 7(245KB) LOS objects, 15% free, 6MB/8MB, paused 19.120ms total 132.593ms
D/URL_DEBUG: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=50.7283825,1.6183893&radius=10000&type=bar&key=****************************************
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 9615(404KB) AllocSpace objects, 4(281KB) LOS objects, 7% free, 7MB/8MB, paused 6.019ms total 53.619ms
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 8022(287KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(64KB) LOS objects, 4% free, 7MB/8MB, paused 6.407ms total 49.642ms
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:4
    Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 4
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 5268(222KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(128KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 8MB/8MB, paused 3.830ms total 104.154ms
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 11375(617KB) AllocSpace objects, 21(743KB) LOS objects, 40% free, 7MB/12MB, paused 5.845ms total 103.471ms
I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 201816006
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 18537(791KB) AllocSpace objects, 11(1408KB) LOS objects, 17% free, 10MB/12MB, paused 10.169ms total 114.008ms
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 18549(1020KB) AllocSpace objects, 75(2MB) LOS objects, 39% free, 9MB/16MB, paused 3.162ms total 110.832ms
```

Does any one of you know why my route don't appear or what is the problem please ? Thanks

Comment: Have you checked your result? or Have you verified whether the for loop is running or not? As it seems, your for loop is not looped even once which is why your `polylineOptions` stays `null` and which is why nothing changes on the map because of that null check. Check the for loop and that result first.

Comment: Effectivily your are true, i put Tost.maketest in the two loop and i don't loop anyone of the two but i don't understand why

Comment: Do you know from what it can come from ?

Comment: Check Your result. You aren't getting a valid result.

Comment: i get my result from an API so i don't understand why it don't work

Comment: If it's an API, check your inputs to it.

Comment: Still don't find... Can i may be give you my github link so you can see my all code ?